# How to insert element using template

Tags: c++

I have some doubts about my insert method. it is compiling, but with no result. I presume that it is containing some coding errors.  Can you help me resolving this? Thanks in advance.

```
private:
 T*             elements;
 int            capacity;
 int            nbElements;
 
 template <class T>
void TableDynamic<T>::insert(const T& element, int index)
 {
 int *temp = new int[capacity] ;
 for(int i =0; i<nbElements; i++)
 {
   temp[i] = element;
 }
 delete[] elements;
 int *elem = new int[capacite];
}
```

Comment: [Edit] your question with a [mcve].  This code doesn't look remotely correct though.

Comment: I am going to assume this is for some sort of school assignment where you are required to use raw, C-style arrays, right?  If not you should be using `std::vector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written some code for you. see if its works for you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// insert element using template
template <class T>
class TableDynamic
{
private:
    T *elements;
    int capacity;
    int nbElements;

public:
    TableDynamic(int capacity)
    {
        this->capacity = capacity;
        this->nbElements = 0;
        this->elements = new T[capacity];
    }

    void insert(const T &element, int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > nbElements)
        {
            cout << "Index out of range" << endl;
            return;
        }
        if (nbElements == capacity)
        {
            cout << "Table is full" << endl;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = nbElements; i > index; i--)
        {
            elements[i] = elements[i - 1];
        }
        elements[index] = element;
        nbElements++;
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nbElements; i++)
        {
            cout << elements[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    TableDynamic<int> table(10);
    table.insert(10, 0);
    table.insert(20, 1);
    table.insert(30, 2);
    // print the table
    table.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be preferrable to use `std::move`: for elements like `std::string` or `std::vector` this can save lot of unnececessary dynamic memory allocations. Instead of the for loop in `insert` `std::move_backward` which does a memberwise move.

Comment: Oupss. How to remove one element?

Comment: `void deleteElement(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= nbElements)
        {
            cout << "Index out of range" << endl;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = index; i < nbElements - 1; i++)
        {
            elements[i] = elements[i + 1];
        }
        nbElements--;
    }
`

Comment: ` C++ != java `

Answer (score 0):

temp and elem variables types should be T* , and in the last line you have wrote capacite, should be capacity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Resizing should only be done, if the capacity is insufficient.

Furthermore you didn't copy any of the old elements over; you simply fill every element with the new element.

Also you're generating an array of `int`s regardless of element type which will only allow for element types `int` or `const int`.

The code should look something like this:

```
template <class T>
void TableDynamic<T>::insert(const T& element, int index)
{
    if ((index > nbElements) || (index < 0))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid index");
    }

    if ((nbElements + 1) > capacity)
    {
        // reallocate array
        auto newCapacity = CalculateNewCapacity(capacity, nbElements + 1); // todo: implement capacity calulation function

        auto temp = std::make_unique<T[]>(newCapacity);
        temp[index] = element; // note copying may result in an error, moving shouldn't, so copy first
        
        // move first half
        std::move(elements, elements + index, temp.get());
        // move second half
        std::move(elements + index, elements + nbElements, temp.get() + (index + 1));

        // replace array
        delete[] elements;
        elements = temp.release();

        capacity = newCapacity;
    }
    else
    {
        // make room for new element
        std::move_backward(elements + index, elements + nbElements, elements + (nbElements + 1));
        // insert new element
        elements[index] = element;
    }
    ++nbElements;
}
```